# how to create an excel file in google app engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create an excel sheet using Google App Engine in python.

my application datastore contains the data of company details like

```
name, business, website,..etc.,.
```

i want to put those details in an excel sheet, is it possible to generate excel file in Google App Engine using python.

can anybody help me!

Answer (score 4):

You can't write to the filesystem in App Engine, so pyexcelerator's save function obviously won't work.

You'll want to take the data pyexcelerator's generating, and instead of writing it to a file either save it as a blob in the Datastore or return it directly to the user's browser.

Comment: I know this is really old thread, but I am new to python, just wondering if you could add a sample code

Answer (score 4):

You may like to consider `xlwt`, a fork of `pyExcelerator` with bug-fixes and on-going enhancements. See `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt` ... disclosure: I'm the maintainer of xlwt.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple suggestion is to create tab seperated files (.tsv) or comma seperated files (.csv), which is very easy to do.
Just use "\t".join(row) and save as .xls/.tsv or ",".join(row) and save as .csv. Excel will know how to handle this. I suggest tab seperated files since tab is a rare character and using it probably means you won't need escaping in your code.

Creating real excel files is an overhead that I think you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyexcelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) to generate excel files

Comment: i tried it, but i am getting error at wb.save('output.xls')
in 
http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/10942_3727616_1

Comment: and i also dont know will app Engine support this "from django.http import HttpResponse " or not in  http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/10942_3727616_2